# HTML create link from a onload() function

Tags: javascript, html

i have a requirement to save url to a.txt file and access the url with some sample.html file.

below is my code to get url from .txt file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function readfile() {
    alert(document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id='iframe' src = 'URL.txt' onload='readfile()' frameBorder='0' >&nbsp;</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

my .txt file contains https://www.google.co.in/

[image]

how to enclose the url with in an anchor tag so that it look like below code

```
<a href="" >Click Here to view</a>
```

Comment: Can you in check in developer window, for any error on 'getElementById('iframe').contentDocument'. I tried the same, I am getting this error "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Answer (score 0):

change your `readfile()` method to

```
function readfile() 
{ 
    var url  = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML += "<a href='" + url + "'> Click Here to view </a>";
}
```

You can try with this if your text file only contains URL

```
var url  = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

you can also create an element by using `document.createElement`

```
var anchor = document.createElement( "a" );
anchor.setAttribute( "href", url );
document.body.append( anchor );
```

Comment: i tried above code but the url is still displaying as plain text but not as a link.

Comment: @Sid in the same method can you do a `console.log(document.body.innerHTML);` and share the output

Comment: i tried console.log(document.body.innerHTML); but still displaying as plain text

Comment: @Sid you can try `document.createElement` method as well. Check my updated post